# How do I run multiple program instances using screen when the program locks the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am attempting to write a script that will load up 6 instances of a games server.

The problem I'm having so far is that the script will open a new screen and load up the program, which then takes over the terminal, only permitting game specific commands. I have to quit the program, which closes the screen session and returns to the previous session, before the script is able to load the next instance of the program.

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
baseUrl=$HOME"/steamcmd/steamapps/common/qlds"
count=0
serverPort=27960

cd $baseUrl

while [ $count -le 5 ]
do 
    screen bash ./$count/run_server_x64.sh +set net_port $serverPort  
    let count=$count+1
    let serverPort=serverPort+$count
done
```

How can I modify this code so that it will continue to loop and load multiple instances?

Comment: Search for how to launch programs in detached screens.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to end the command to launch the server with `&` to ensure it becomes backgrounded. Then each instance of the server will be placed into a background task. Like this:

```
screen bash ./$count/run_server_x64.sh +set net_port $serverPort &
```

I am not quite sure what you want but that will at least ensure that the default behaviour of bash to wait for the current command to finish before running another is avoided and the instances will all launch without the previous ones exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not open 6 windows in a *single* `screen` session? This is more or less what `screen` is made for.

You can open new windows with `<Control-C> c` and start another server there.

Take a look at the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), or this [quick reference](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference) on how to navigate those windows.